# Why is the program ending after the last board is drawn

Tags: c

I have a program which displays a board for a tictactoe game which is then cleared and then the next state is displayed but after the last draw_board function is called the program ends.

I don't know how this is possible since there's no code which could exit the program prematurely

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void draw_board(char board[9]){
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0], board[1], board[2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[3], board[4], board[5]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[6], board[7], board[8]);
    printf("\n");
}
void wait(float seconds) {
    clock_t end_wait = clock() + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while (clock() < end_wait) {}
}
void clear(){
    #ifdef _WIN32
        system("cls"); // Windows
    #else
        system("clear"); // Linux/Unix
    #endif
}

void ascii_art()
{
    char board[9];
    //initialises an empty board
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        board[i] = ' ';
    }
    int moves[7] = {0,8,6,3,2,4,1};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        //update the board array with each move where the first move is an x then o and so on
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            board[moves[i]] = 'x';
        }
        else{
            board[moves[i]] = 'o';
        }
        //prints out the board waits 0.3 seconds then clears the console
        draw_board(board);
        wait(0.3);
        clear();
    }
    //finally print the final state of the board and don't clear the screen
    board[moves[8]] = 'x';
    draw_board(board);
    //this print statement is not in the output
    printf("End\n");
    //this was a suggestion from chatGPT
    fflush(stdout);
}



int main(void)
{
    //runs the function which prints the state of the game after each move
    ascii_art();
    //this print statement is not being run
    printf("\n Done!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least this for loop for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ should be written like for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

Comment: `moves` has 7 items in it indexed 0 .. 6. Your program accesses that array out of bounds in this loop `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`. https://godbolt.org/z/GTYP9z53f `board[moves[8]] = 'x';` is also out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int moves[7] = {0,8,6,3,2,4,1};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
```

`moves` only has indexes 0-6 but is addressed at 7 causing `SIGBUS` error.

And `board[moves[8]] = 'x';` should be `board[moves[6]] = 'x';`

[image: done]